# Right or wrong: "Am I correct?"

Tags: phrase-usage, questions

Is it correct to ask:

> "Am I correct?"

The context is [checking mathematical reasoning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317332/finite-fields-and-their-subfields).

I typed it down and is haunted by an odd feeling that there is some mistake with it! Should I prefer "Am I right?" to the above?

Comment: Those two sentences can be used as synonyms, depending on the context. Could you explain a bit more in detail? I'm not entirely sure what you're asking and no context is given at all.

Comment: @Sander Towards the end of [this question in math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317332/finite-fields-and-their-subfields)

Comment: @JessePFrancis In that question you don't ask "am I correct" or "am I right". You ask "is it correct", which is a little different. Are you asking if you could replace that with "am I correct"?

Comment: @JessePFrancis, in most circumstances, it would be fine to use that particular phrase, with very few exceptions. Am I correct? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think "Am I correct?" is. Correctness is something all-encompassing.

To "be right" is less than that, sometimes you're right sometimes you're wrong.

Correctness applies to a mathematical solution, result or proof and as such is absolute. You wouldn't say: "The solution is right."

But you can ask: "Am I correct in assuming.." or, of course "Is this/my solution correct?".

Which more or less is how your question reads now. Good..

Comment: *In context*, "am I correct?" is limited by the context and is almost always fine. This hard separation between right and correct doesn't really exist in conventional usage.

Comment: Talking about math, I think Am I correct (except on my question) works! Thank you!